# Issues with PySpark on Jupyter notebook with .show() DataFrame once it is passed through a function

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-sql

Working with Jupyter notebook and PySpark. I firstly create a dataframe and execute `.printSchematic()` and `.show()` fine:

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Example dataset
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'integers': [1, 2, 3],
     'floats': [-1.0, 0.5, 2.7],
     'integer_arrays': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]}
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

**Result**:

```
root
 |-- floats: double (nullable = true)
 |-- integer_arrays: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- integers: long (nullable = true) 

+------+--------------+--------+
|floats|integer_arrays|integers|
+------+--------------+--------+
|  -1.0|        [1, 2]|       1|
|   0.5|     [3, 4, 5]|       2|
|   2.7|  [6, 7, 8, 9]|       3|
+------+--------------+--------+
```

Then I pass it through a UDF and `.printSchema()` is fine but `.show()` shows an error

**Code**:

```
# Python function
def square(x):
    return x**2

# UDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
square_udf_int = udf(lambda z: square(z), IntegerType())
new_df = df.select('integers',
                   'floats',
                   square_udf_int('integers').alias('int_squared'),
                   square_udf_int('floats').alias('float_squared'))
new_df.printSchema()
new_df.show()
```

**Result**:

```
root
 |-- integers: long (nullable = true)
 |-- floats: double (nullable = true)
 |-- int_squared: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- float_squared: integer (nullable = true)
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-246-f51d3e043cb1> in <module>()
----> 1 new_df.show()

D:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.pyc in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    348         """
    349         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 350             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    351         else:
    352             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

D:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

D:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

D:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5498.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.doExecute(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BaseLimitExec$class.inputRDDs(limit.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalLimitExec.inputRDDs(limit.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. I get expected output DataFrame, although the `float_squared` column is all `null` due to the return type mismatch.

Comment: Are you also using Spark 2.3.1 and Hadoop 2.7?